# shared folder missing some subfolders

Tags: macos, network, sharing

I have a local account and a network account on my MacBook Pro (Late 2011). I am running Yosemite 10.10.3.

I mainly do my work on my local account and then when necessary I log onto my network account.

I wish to share my `users/localusername/work/` folder and all the subfolders with `users/networkusername/work/`.

When I follow the directions given i.e. go to `system preferences/sharing` select the folder I wish to share and then the user and permissions `read/write`, all seems ok except that a number of subfolders (not all) are completely missing.

It is also doesn't work in reverse. If I do something in the `networkusername/work`  it is not updated in the `localusername/work`.

Any hints or suggestions?

Comment: Did you set up a mount point for the shared folder at /Users/networkusername/work/ ? Otherwise, I'm not sure what you mean when you say you want to share one folder with the other. Also, without it being a mount point, changes to the networkusername/work folder will never reflect in the username/work folder.

Comment: @tubedogg In my local log in I went into system preferences/sharing. I then added the folder /work to sharing and I gave networkuser read/write privileges. I didn't mount anything. Don't even know how to do that! Thought I was doing well with the above...!

Comment: @tubedogg just re read your comment and may have misunderstood or misread. Ignore my first reply for the moment and I'll check stuff later and come back to you.

Comment: OK, so you have /Users/localusername/work/ and you shared that with networkusername. When you login with networkusername, how are you accessing the shared folder?

Comment: @tubedogg just through finder. The shared folder appears when I log on with networkusername but some sub folders are missing. If I create a folder in networkusername it does not appear in localusername. I must check do file changes save and pass back and forth. Not on Mbp at moment, so can't verify immediately. Should have checked this out earlier, apologies.

Comment: Ok just discovered the best way to do this is put the work folder in localusername public folder. Then share with networkusername and all works.

Comment: The public folder is already shared...that's why it's called public. That said, it's also available to any other users on the system. Try this: while logged in as networkusername, in Finder press Command-G and then enter `/Users/localusername/work`. Does that open for you? If so, drag it to your favorites in the sidebar. This is the shared folder and changes made in this folder will reflect while logged into either account.

Comment: Shift-Command-G, sorry